# Trying to grab highest and lowest non-zero or below from int input but negative int keeps getting passed into output

Tags: python, while-loop

This program is intended to read a list of integers into a list as long as the integers are greater than zero and then output the smallest and largest integers in the list.

> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> 10
> 5
> 3
> 21
> 2
> -6
> ```
>
> the output is:
>
> ```
> 2 and 21
> ```
>
> The list of integers will have at least 2 values.

This is the code I wrote to begin with. With the provided input, this outputs -6 and 21 when it should output 2 and 21.

```
user_input = int(input())
input_list = []

while 0 < user_input:
    user_input = int(input())
    input_list.append(user_input)

print(f'{min(input_list)} and {max(input_list)}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. It seems like you need to learn how to debug, so check out [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. I'll save you a bit of time though and tell you this code doesn't raise any compiler warnings or even any linter warnings; it's well-organized, just the logic is wrong. The "rubber duck" step is the main thing I think will help, if not that then the debugger. Lastly, for future questions, check out [ask].

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. What is the order of events - immediately after getting an input from the user, what will happen next: putting it into the list, or checking the condition for the `while` loop? What *should* happen next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The code below solves the problem.

The input function would return a string containing space separate numbers. Iterate through the string using for loop. For each number check if it is positive, if so, add to another list and then report the min and max

```
user_input = input().split()
input_list = []

for i in user_input:
    act_num = int(i)
    if act_num >0:
        input_list.append(act_num)

print(f'{min(input_list)} and {max(input_list)}')
```

edit : just realized, i think, you want to stop taking input as soon as a negative number comes, in that case, use the following code. Remember during input, press enter after each number
Just swap the two lines because otherwise you are never adding the first input to the list

```
user_input = int(input())
input_list = []

while 0 < user_input:
    input_list.append(user_input)
    user_input = int(input())
    

print(f'{min(input_list)} and {max(input_list)}')
```

Comment: There was a formatting issue with the question that affected the input. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[@DareGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77055215/22390653) already provided a solution, I am adding an explanation as to why you are getting negative numbers inside `input_list`.

This is your code, check comments beside significant lines:

```py
user_input = int(input()) 
input_list = []

while 0 < user_input: # 0. while "user_input" > 0
    user_input = int(input()) # 1. take an input `string`, convert to `int` and assign value to 'user_input'
    input_list.append(user_input) # 2. append 'user_input' to list  

print(f'{min(input_list)} and {max(input_list)}')
```

1. Notice *comment#0* has quoted `"user_input"`. This is different from *comment#1* and *comment#2* where `'user_input'` has single quote. That's because they are same variable in different `state`. `'user_input'` (single quote) is ahead of time with respect to `"user_input"`. Essentially, double quoted `"user_input"` is the previous value of single quoted `'user_input'`
2. When you push your negative number, it will fail the `while` loop *after* it has already been appended inside the `input_list`. In other words, a sample execution:

```
"user_input" = 5 # Side Note: you are never saving this inside input_list btw 
input_list = []

while 0 < 5 # True, continue
  'user_input' = 1
  input_list.append(1) # [1]

# "user_input" = 1
while 0 < 1 # True, continue
  'user_input' = 2
  input_list.append(2) # [1, 2]

# "user_input" = 2
while 0 < 2 # True, continue
  'user_input' = -1
  input_list.append(-1) # [1, 2, -1]

# "user_input" = -1
while 0 < -1 # False, break
```

To fix this, you need to follow what @DareGhost suggested, swap the two lines, so that you are only appending *after* checking your previous input in the `while` loop exit condition, not immediately after you take your input. So,

```py
while 0 < user_input:
    user_input = int(input())
    input_list.append(user_input)
```

becomes

```py
while 0 < user_input:
    input_list.append(user_input)
    user_input = int(input())
```

Answer (score -1):

DareGhost provided an effective solution, which I implemented:

```
user_input = 1
input_list = []

while 0 < user_input:
    user_input = int(input())
    if 0 < user_input:
        input_list.append(user_input)

print(f'{min(input_list)} and {max(input_list)}')
```

I set user_input = 1 outside the while loop just as a placeholder so it could be initialized.

I also did not swap the lines within the while loop but instead utilized the first suggested method.

Comment: If [dareghost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15468784/dareghost) already answered, why did you post this?

Comment: I posted this because what I ended up doing is a bit different from what DareGhost provided. I thought it would be helpful to provide what I implemented and clearly state what I did. If that is not helpful, I can delete this.